# Complexity of Set.prototype.delete()

Tags: javascript

MDN doesn't mention the complexity of [Set.prototype.delete()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/delete). Usually, deletion in a set is O(1). Could anybody quote a spec guaranteeing this for any javascript set implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee of the time complexity of `delete` in the spec, and JavaScript engines are free to choose the data structure and algorithm as they see fit. Even if it is O(1) for a certain implementation, it is not something to rely on.

https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-set-objects

Note that there is mention of sublinear access time, but no mention of the complexity of delete operation.

Answer (score -1):

> Set objects must be implemented using either hash tables or other mechanisms that, on average, provide access times that are sublinear on the number of elements in the collection.

http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-set-objects

Comment: Is `access` times same as `delete` time?